# How to set Google Maps api in QML

Tags: qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, qml

I'm having problem probably setting Google Maps Api in my code. My program needs to use google map satellite view and I have to add merkers, draw lines and other stuff like this. This is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Rectangle {
id: mainWindow
width: 512
height: 512
visible: true

ListModel{
    id:dummyModel
    ListElement {
        Latitude: 47.212047
        Longitude: -1.551647
        Label: "something"
        Orientation: 0
        Color:"transparent"
    }
}

Plugin {
    id: googleMaps
    name: "googlemaps" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
    // specify plugin parameters if necessary
     PluginParameter {
         name:"googlemaps.maps.apikey"
         value:"<*********************>"      // here is the problem
     }

}

Map {
    id: myMap
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: googleMaps
    activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[1]

    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
    zoomLevel: 14

    MapItemView{
        id:dynamicMapObject
        model: dummyModel
        delegate: MapQuickItem {
            coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(Latitude,Longitude)
            sourceItem:  Text{
                width: 100
                height: 50
                text: model.Label
                rotation: model.Orientation
                opacity: 0.6
                color: model.Color
            }
        }
    }

    MapPolyline {
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'green'
            path: [
                { latitude: 59.92, longitude: 10.77 },
                { latitude: 59.96, longitude: 10.78 },
                { latitude: 59.99, longitude: 10.76 },
                { latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.74 }
            ]
    }

    MapCircle {
      //a static item (fixed real dimension) always at 100m east of the map center
      id:prova
      center: myMap.center.atDistanceAndAzimuth(100,90)
      opacity:0.8
      color:"red"
      radius:30

    }
}

MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
       acceptedButtons:  Qt.RightButton

       onClicked: {
            if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton)
            {
                dummyModel.append({
                    "Latitude": myMap.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)).latitude ,"Longitude": myMap.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)).longitude ,
                    "Label": "abc" , "Color": "red",
                    "Orientation":Number(3), })
            }
       }
}

Button{
    id:buttonMap
    text:"Click to add name"
    onClicked: {
        if(buttonMap.text == "Click to add name")
        {
            buttonMap.text = "Click to cancel name"
            myMap.activeMapType = myMap.supportedMapTypes[3]
        }
        else
        {
            buttonMap.text = "Click to add name"
            myMap.activeMapType = myMap.supportedMapTypes[1]
        }
    }
}

GroupBox{
       title:"map types"
       ComboBox{
           model:myMap.supportedMapTypes
           textRole:"description"
           onCurrentIndexChanged: myMap.activeMapType = myMap.supportedMapTypes[currentIndex]
       }
 }
}
```

When I compile the code in debug Mode everything works, but in release nothing is shown. Of course it's a problem of google api key. Does somebody know how to add them? I tried following this topic (https://forum.qt.io/topic/66725/open-source-map-plug-in-for-qml/24), but I can't get it works.

I also tried all the google maps api key available here (https://developers.google.com/maps/web/) but none of them works.

Does somebody know which api key is the correct one from the above for my purpose?
Am I missing something in the plugin parameters?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to get your own API key? If not here's a [guide on how to do it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). As for the qml plugin bit, sorry but I can't help you there.

Comment: Yes, I already have a project in the Google Api Console and in the DashBoard I can see that all the google maps api are enabled.

Comment: But did you create your own API key in Credentials section of developer console? https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279

Comment: @xomena Yes I created my own api key. I think the problem is on the code side.